# What is the importance of Oracle client in Python script?

Tags: python-3.x, cx-oracle, oracleclient

I'm working with python 3.6 on ubuntu 16.04 and trying to connect with Oracle database which is installed in another machine. So i have installed "cx_Oracle" python module by following this [link](http://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#install-cx-oracle). 
Now, my doubt is what is the necessity to install oracle client in my machine when i need to access the database from another machine in my python script?

Comment: your question is why do you need a client to access a database server ? or why do you need a client with cx_Oracle ?

Comment: What is the use of installing oracle client(in my machine) to access Oracle database(exists another machine) by using cx_Oracle module in Python?

Comment: cx_Oracle is a kind of wrapper on top of the client,  http://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#oracle-client-and-oracle-database-interoperability

Comment: What's the use of installing a web browser if you can get HTML printed in the terminal? In other words, do you want to figure out how to build a network connection to the database yourself, or use a client library that handles it all for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Oracle Client libraries provide all the necessary network connectivity (e.g. things like network encryption), connection management (e.g. connection pooling), high availability features, cross platform and Oracle-version support, data caching, etc etc etc.  They are used by many different user and applications.  They have significant engineering in them, not to mention testing.

cx_Oracle makes calls to the Oracle Client libraries (which are freely available in Oracle Instant Client), so you need those libraries.

Comment: i think you need to register in order to be able to download it.

Comment: There is no charge.